# Import numbers from a separate file and save them as a list

Tags: python-3.x, list, import

I have the following numbers saved as a separate text-file called `sample.txt`: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`

Now I want to import these values ​​from the separate file and save them as a list in python. I use the following command:

`def imported_numbers(filename):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f: #open the file
          list = f.readlines() #put the lines to a variable (list).
     print(list)
imported_number('sample.txt')`

However, when running this code in python I get the following error message: 
`"NameError: name 'sample' is not defined".`

Does anyone have a clue about what might be wrong with my code? I have the text file in the same folder as the python file.

Thanks in advance.

/Alex

Comment: Can you include the part where you call the function? Also, it should be `open(filename, 'r')`

Comment: `imported_numbers(sample.txt)`

Comment: it has to be `imported_number('sample.txt')` you are missing the quotes. Or `imported_number(filename='sample.txt')`

Comment: You mean like this:                                                                                              `def imported_numbers(filename):
       with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
            list = f.readlines() 
       print(list)                                                                                                                    
  imported_number('sample.txt')`

Comment: Now I have changed the code so that it stands as in my initial question. However, this is also wrong because I get: NameError: name 'imported_number' is not defined

Comment: it's `imported_numbers` not `number` lol, with the `s`

Comment: Lol!!! Thanks for your help Luke Dinh! This time it worked perfect! :)

Comment: Glad to help :)